# Extract data from xml code and convert it into an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, xml

After sending a request to a webserver in python, I received XML code and I applied few changes on it

```
import re

s='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://emts.erpguru.in/">{"data":[{"Id":0,"IsSuccess":true,"Msg":"MobileNo Already Exists"}] }</string>'

result = re.search('"data":\[{(.*?)}', s)
j= (result.group(1)).split(',')
print(j[2])
```

output : `"Msg":"MobileNo Already Exists"`

I need a more efficient way to convert XML result into an array, so that
`print(j[“Msg”])`
would give result
`MobileNo Already Exists`

Comment: There is a module for XML in Python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom Combine this with the JSON library (`import json` and `json.loads(some_string)`), as your string contains JSON nested in XML.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for XML in Python: [`minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom) Combine this with the JSON library, as your string contains JSON nested in XML:

```py
import json
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString


s = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://emts.erpguru.in/">{"data":[{"Id":0,"IsSuccess":true,"Msg":"MobileNo Already Exists"}] }</string>'

dom = parseString(s)
json_string = dom.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue
j = json.loads(json_string)
print(j["data"][0].get("Msg"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method. This library uses regex implementation.

```
import json
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://emts.erpguru.in/">{"data":[{"Id":0,"IsSuccess":true,"Msg":"MobileNo Already Exists"}] }</string>'

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
s = doc.string.html
# Or
s = doc.select('string').html
result = json.loads(s)
print (result["data"][0]["Msg"])
```

Result:

```
MobileNo Already Exists
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples